# Count only unequal preceding siblings

Tags: xslt

I have a quick question to my XSLT 1.0 problem.

My payload looks like this

```
<Document_Lines>
      <row>
        <ItemCode>153231105</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>24.000</Quantity>
        <ShipDate>22.12.2021 00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Charge>0311232021</Charge>
        <MhdDate>02.11.2026 00:00:00</MhdDate>
        <UomCode>ST</UomCode>
        <BaseType>17</BaseType>
        <BaseEntry>10</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>001</BaseLine>
      </row>
      <row>
        <ItemCode>153105</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>12.000</Quantity>
        <ShipDate>22.12.2021 00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Charge>03112320212</Charge>
        <MhdDate>12.05.2026 00:00:00</MhdDate>
        <UomCode>ST</UomCode>
        <BaseType>17</BaseType>
        <BaseEntry>10</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>001</BaseLine>
      </row>
      <row>
        <ItemCode>153466101</ItemCode>
        <Quantity>36.000</Quantity>
        <ShipDate>22.12.2021 00:00:00</ShipDate>
        <Charge>0212123321</Charge>
        <MhdDate>01.12.2026 00:00:00</MhdDate>
        <UomCode>ST</UomCode>
        <BaseType>17</BaseType>
        <BaseEntry>10</BaseEntry>
        <BaseLine>003</BaseLine>
      </row>
</Document_Lines>
```

and I need to get an output like this

```
<row>
<Charge>0311232021</Charge>
<Quantity>25</Charge>
<LineNum>0</LineNum>
</row>
<row>
<Charge>0311232021</Charge>
<Quantity>12</Charge>
<LineNum>0</LineNum>
</row>
<row>
<Charge>0212123321</Charge>
<Quantity>36</Charge>
<LineNum>1</LineNum>
</row>
```

So it should only count the `LineNum` when the `ItemCode` before is unequal to the `Itemcode`.

My solution was something like:

```
count(//iwss2:row[not(preceding-sibling::iwss2:row/iwss2:ItemCode = $itemCode)])
```

but with this, the `LineNum` will be
`0,0,2` instead of `0,0,1`

Comment: Consider to cut your sample data to a minimum to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The expected result for your specification of *"count the `LineNum` when the `ItemCode` before is unequal to the `Itemcode`"* is `0,1,2`, not `0,1,1`.  (Actually, it should be *count the `row`*, as there is no  `LineNum` in the input). If you want something else, then clarify.

Comment: No my result needs to be 0,1,1 as the Itemcode is the same for the first 2 rows..

Comment: In the data you've shown us, each input row has a different ItemCode.

Comment: Assuming it was your intent that the second input row should have the same ItemCode as the first, this becomes a standard grouping question. Group the input rows in the standard way with ItemCode as the grouping key (Muenchian grouping for XSLT 1.0, xsl:for-each-group for XSLT 2.0), then number the rows with the group using position().

Comment: If the ItemCode were the same for the first 2 rows then the expected result would be `0,0,2` because the 3rd row has 2 preceding siblings with a different ItemCode. This seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is the *real* purpose here?